# An example of a chain ring with certain property

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, valuation-theory

We say a commutative ring $R$
is a chain ring whenever its ideals form a chain with respect to inclusion. Is there a commutative chain ring $R$ that satisfies the following properties?

Property 1. $R$ has a non-finitely generated prime ideal $P$ with $P^2=0$.

Property 2. The unique maximal ideal, say $M$, of $R$ is principal and Krull dimension $R$ is one (the unique chain of prime ideals is $P\subsetneq M$).

Property 3. If $M=(x)$ then $x$ is regular (that is $ann (x)=0$) and $P=\bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N}M^i$.

Answer (score 1):

Try $$R=k[[t]][s,s/t,s/t^2,\ldots]/(s^2,s^2/t^2,s^2/t^4,\ldots)$$

$R= k[[t]]\oplus k((t)) s$, $P=k((t)) s$, $M=(t)$, $(t)^k = t^k k[[t]]\oplus k((t)) s$.

Comment: Is the maximal ideal cyclic?

Comment: Why do you mean with cyclic?

Comment: $M=(t, s ,s/t,...)/(s^2, s^2/t^2, ...)$ is not principal (cyclic=generated by an element)

Comment: $M=(t)$ that's why I added all the $s/t^k$ to the ring

Comment: Is there any reference for such a ring? I am not familiar with this ring.

Comment: What is mysterious to you? The ring is $k[[t]]\oplus s k((t))$ with $(a+bs)(c+ds)=ac+(ad+bc)s$

Comment: I can't understand why the ring is a chain ring. Is it the trivial extension?

Comment: If no $t^k \in I$ then $I\subset P = s k((t))$ so it is either $P$ or $s t^k k[[t]]$ or $\{0\}$. If some $t^k \in I$ then $I = (t^n)= t^n k[[t]]+P$. Whence the ideals are ordered by inclusion.

Comment: $A=k[[t]]\oplus s k[[s]]k((t))$ is a valuation ring (with value group $\Bbb{Z}^2$ with lexicographic order), its ideals are ordered, and $R = A/(s^2)$.

Comment: @reuns Can value groups be associated to valuation rings that aren't domains?  I ask because your ring has zero divisors... I have no literature on either so I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @rschwieb My ring is the quotient of a valuation ring, not a valuation ring itself. If $A$ is a valuation ring then the ideals of $A/I$ are ordered.

Comment: @reuns I see, I missed that there were two rings in play.